# Raphael.js Javascript onclick not working on web site but fine locally

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, onclick, raphael, settimeout

This is a really strange bug I don't understand. I'm using Raphael.js graphics library successfully to create a nice UI interaction hosted on a Sharepoint site. Everything works fine when running locally. However, when I run the HTML on the web server, the UI renders but the onclick functions on my UI buttons (in the case here, I call them raphaelCircles which are Raphael Circle objects) often do not work (I'll explain what I mean by "often" below).

```
raphaelCircle.node.onclick = function ()
{
   //Do stuff. Works locally fine, but on on the Sharepoint website.
}
```

I've tried sprinkling in some setTimeouts in my scripts to delay script and XML loading before the onclick functions are assigned, but to no avail. Oddly, the thing that works is when I draw a rectangle right after the onclick is assigned:

```
var frame = _paperNodeLayer.rect(0, 0, _canvasWidth - 2, _canvasHeight - 2);
frame.attr('stroke', 'silver');
```

It's weird, it's like if I give Raphael more to "do" after assigning a click handler, it works on the site. If I don't, it only works locally. Any ideas?  Like I said, I thought maybe I was trying to do too much in my code and the drawing of the rectangle slowed it down enough, but I delayed the object creations and click assignments quite a bit and it didn't seem to make a difference. Only drawing a rectangle on the screen seemed to work.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Have you attempted to set a break point inside of your ``onclick`` handler to see what the state of the page is at the time the event is being triggered?

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see how that will work since the event is NOT being triggered. That's the whole point.

Comment: I see, sorry for the misunderstanding. My knowledge of Raphael isn't the best, so I don't know how qualified I am to answer this. My thought is that perhaps drawing the rectangle is causing the canvas to "update", thus actually registering that you have an associated click handler. Is there any way you can just force the canvas to refresh itself, and see if that has the same effect as drawing your rectangle?

Comment: You need to post more of the code, ideally on a jsfiddle so we can test. It sounds a little like the code is loading some stuff in, and the handler is reliant on something from that and the delay is causing the problem, so you may want to look into adding a closure, or callback on when its run. Can't really say without code to look at.